# Narrowing parameter of callback based on discriminated union key

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface Foo {
    type: 'foo'
}

interface Bar {
    type: 'bar'
}

type MyEvent = Foo | Bar

function listen(_parameterType: 'foo', _callback: (event: Foo) => void): void;
function listen(_parameterType: 'bar', _callback: (event: Bar) => void): void;
function listen(_parameterType: MyEvent['type'], _callback: (event: MyEvent) => void): void {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIDkMm1uAvrrqJLIigEJxQ76ES5KtQBGvBs1xCUAWWIBRAG4RwyALxpMyAD7IeUFjACuIBGGDoQyADbAAzpBAAKAPqlecALYR2AFTJKGjp0agAaZFcEOBsbcQQAaypnCBVwKgx0AEoNAD5kJXRgABMsqkKSgG5cEzMLK1sHJzcPKG9faADhGnEocMjo2Pik5BS0sCoDHPV8itLyouLq2vNLaztHVRbPH39AqnllVTAAbWoZagBdCKiYuMQRseODxXHp2cWygsWcRiA)

I would expect this to compile, and that if a consumer subscribes to an event of type `foo`, they could simply do `listen('foo', (event: Foo) => {})`. This doesn't work, however, and the compiler spits out that

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

Why doesn't this work? `MyEvent` is a union of both of the events type here, so I'm surprised it doesn't. Is there a way to achieve what I want without just forcing my consumers to cast their event type (or perform the discriminated union check themselves)?

Comment: Function parameters are contravariant. Yes, Foo and Bar are assignable to MyEvent, but not the other way around.

Comment: Consider using generics instead: https://tsplay.dev/Ndyrnm

Comment: That's a nifty solution. Is there a way I can somehow assert the keys of `ListenMap` are also a member of `MyEvent['type']`? I think I can do it on the function signature with `T extends keyof ListenMap & MyEvent['type']`, but maybe there's a cleaner way. Regardless, please feel free to post this as an answer :)

Comment: @kelsny Ah contravariance... been a minute since I had to think about that. I just found this great blog post to help future travelers, too! https://sammart.in/post/2021-07-25-typescript-function-type-parameter-contravariance/
Thanks!

Comment: try this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIDkMm1uAvrrqJLIigEJxQ76ES5KtQBGvBs1xCUAWWIBRAG4RwyALxpMyAD7IeUFjACuIBGGDoQyADbAAzpBAAKAPqlecALYR2AFTJKGjp0agAaZFcEOBsbcQQAaypnCBVwKgx0AEoNAD5kJXRgABMsqkKSgG5cEzMLK1sHJzcPKG9faADhGnEocMjo2Pik5BS0sCoDHPV8itLyouLq2vNLaztHVRbPH39AqnllVTAAbWoZagBdCKiYuMQRseOM7QAyfV5p2cWygsWcRhAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error here because function parameter types are **contravariant**. Yes, `Foo` and `Bar` are assignable to `MyEvent`, but since it's contravariant, you need the inverse to be true (`MyEvent` should be assignable to `Foo` or `Bar`).

Instead of messing with overloads and hacking variance I would rather use a generic parameter:

```
type ListenMap = {
    foo: Foo;
    bar: Bar;
};

function listen<T extends keyof ListenMap>(_parameterType: T, _callback: (event: ListenMap[T]) => void): void {}
```

If you want to add an assertion that the keys of the map are valid, you could also do that. One way is show below:

```
type ListenMap = {
    foo: Foo;
    bar: Bar;
    invalid: string;
};

type _ListenMapAssertion<T extends MyEvent["type"] = keyof ListenMap> = T;
//                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIDkMm1uAvrrqJLIigEJxQ76ES5KtQBGvBs1xCUAWWIBRAG4RwyALxpMyAD7IeUFjOQAZYAGdIIWXFIb+hZHXRUM6ANwCC4qFQOeAegCCUCU4ABtgABMqSyhQAHN3ZCDkBQAldIB5dKZPaTIUAH0zS1UbUgBBc3NoMGB0EAAeABVkCAAPKyjzZHllVTAAbQAiGRGAXXsAawhidBhTCysKgD57FvyYAFcQBHrG5Eiy5rbO7t7Z+cXSldtVgAoi0l44AFsIdhbCqhaAGmQRQQEXC4gQ0yoDwgKnAVFu5VsQxaEwAlBp1kp0NEUVRMdEcFJjlYHrR6ACoTCwGj1Os8KljBYnJgvO1KbhUsgAHoAfiYKPcQA)